# Xubuntu brightness keeps resetting if too low

Tags: xubuntu, brightness, indicator, backlight

For health reasons I have to set brightness to a very low value. However, after restart the value always resets - not to a full brightness, but to some preset minimal value. This seems like a good idea, you don't have to worry that you accidentally turn the screen black and will have to edit text config files in the console. But this value is still too high for me.

Moreover, display brightness indicator does not reflect this change: I lower  the brightness, after reboot the indicator is still low but brightness has slightly risen. I push the indicator lower still and so on. After several restarts the indicator is close to zero and brightness still the same.

Is there any way to keep the system from applying minimal brightness value or even better a way to change this value?

Comment: What release of Xubuntu?  (Xubuntu has now completed it's move to GTK3 so currently we don't know how far along the move you're using).  The following should be useful (https://superuser.com/questions/1279727/xfce-change-brightness-steps-and-or-change-brightness-key-behavior), but you'll need to adapt for your Xubuntu release (you didn't provide)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks, but `xbacklight` does not seem to be working (`xbacklight +10` etc does not change brightness without output) and I am not keen on recompiling the power manager. I am on Xubuntu 18.04.4, Xfce about shows 4.12.